# Count Query with range

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Good Day! I need a way to query the number of members per specific age range
my table looks like this

```
member | Age 
     1 | 15 
     2 | 15 
     3 | 17 
     4 | 18 
     5 | 18 
     6 | 18 
     7 | 20
```

I need to determine the number of members per specific age, but the thing is, the filter comes with a format of range which is 15-20, 21-25, 30-35 and so on.
For example if I selected range from 15-20, I need to count the number of members per spcific age of 15,16,17,18,19,20.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
select
tb.Age `Age`,
count(tb.member) `count`
from
(select
member,
case when Age >=15 & Age<20 then '15-20'
     when Age >=20 & Age<25 then '20-25'
     when Age >=25 & Age<30 then '25-30'
     else '30+' end `Age`
from tablename ) as tb
group by `Age`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want **select range** you should use **BETWEEN Condition in MySQL**.
MySQL BETWEEN Condition will return the records where expression is within the range of value1 and value2.

using between your query will be-

```
SELECT Count(member) as number_of_member FROM tablename where Age BETWEEN 15 and 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
tb.Age `Age`,
count(tb.member) `count`
from(
select
member,
(case when age between 15 and 20 then '15-20'
  when age between 21 and 25 then '20-25'
 when age between 26 and 30 then '26-30'
 else '30+' end)age
from mytable ) as tb
group by age
```